# oozie shell action with spark-submit

Tags: shell, apache-spark, oozie

i am trying to run spark-submit from a shell wrapper. while the job runs fine from command line but failed when scheduling through oozie.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.handle(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:394)
at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitOptionParser.parse(SparkSubmitOptionParser.java:163)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:97)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

here is my workflow:

```
    <workflow-app name="OozieTest1" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="CopyTest"/>
   <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
<action name="CopyTest">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <exec>lib/copy.sh</exec>
              <argument>hdfs://xxxxxx/user/xxxxxx/oozie-test/file-list/xxx_xxx_201610.lst</argument>
              <argument>hdfs://xxxxxx/user/xxxxxx/oozie-test/sample</argument>
              <argument>hdfs://xxxxxx/user/xxxxxx/oozie-test/output</argument>
              <argument>IMMUN</argument>
              <argument>N</argument>
              <argument>hdfs://xxxxxx/user/xxxxxx/oozie-test/resources/script-constants.properties</argument>
             <file>hdfs://xxxxxx/user/xxxxxx/oozie-test/lib/copy.sh#copy.sh</file> 
             <file>hdfs://xxxxxx/user/xxxxxx/oozie-test/lib/xxxx_Integration.jar#xxxx_Integration.jar</file>
        <capture-output/>
        </shell>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what version of spark, hadoop and oozie you use. But most probably you have some dependency issues. (jar is missing) I would really recommend to check your dependencies. Here you can find the full working example [here](http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/how-to-submit-spark-job-through-oozie/):

In this example the hadoop and spark versions are following:

```
<hadoop.version>2.6.0-cdh5.4.7</hadoop.version>
<spark.version>1.3.0-cdh5.4.7</spark.version>
```